# Equivalent of css "position: relative" to move slighty a graphic

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have a header with two columns; On the first column, I have an image (the logo) and I would like to slightly adjust its position. Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\tt\begin{multicols}{2}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.eps}\vfill\columnbreak some more text...\end{multicols}}
```

Is it possible to move a little bit to the top/left my image?

[edit]

here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\begin{multicols}{2}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{logo.eps}\vfill\columnbreak Right column text\end{multicols}}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{200 mm}
\setlength\textwidth{17cm}
\setlength\headheight{3cm}
\setlength\headsep{2cm}
\begin{document}
some content
\end{document}
```

thanks

Comment: I don't think that `multicols` is the best way to do this; how should the picture be in relation to the side text?

Comment: my design is based on a grid that's why I used `multicols`. I'm open to other suggestions if `multicols` is a problem. Thanks

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out possible solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For the logo, just approximate dimensions are sufficient.

Comment: Here it the minimal working example!

Comment: Where should the image be placed? Slightly higher and a bit offset into the left margin? Do you need the rule below the header?

Comment: @egreg
no I don't need the rule, and yes, slightly higher and a bit offset into the left margin!

Answer (score 2):

`multicols` is not the best for a header; I suggest using a tabular; moreover, `geometry` makes defining page dimensions easier.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  top=1cm, % top margin
  left=2cm, % left margin
  textwidth=17cm,
  textheight=20cm,
  includehead, % the header is included in the computations
  headheight=3cm, % height of the header
  headsep=2cm,
  heightrounded, % to have an integer number of lines
]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{url}    % for demonstration purposes
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

%% Define the text in the header
\newcommand{\headertext}{%
  The name of the firm\newline
  Address \newline
  \url{http://firm.com}
}

%% Let's define the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[L]{%
  %% assuming the width of the logo is 4cm, we put it 1cm left in the margin
  %% and we cut 3cm (width - offset) from the remaining space, for the text
  \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-2\tabcolsep}@{}}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{logo.eps}}
  & \headertext
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

It's not difficult to separate more the logo from the header text

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Could you explain the meaning of `@{}lp{\dimexpr\textwidth-3cm-2\tabcolsep}@{}`? (I mean especially the `@{}lp{}@{}` structure)

Comment: `p{<dimension>}` states that the column is a "paragraph" column. I set it to be as wide as the `\textwidth` minus the offset for the logo and the intercolumn space (between the first and second column it is `2\tabcolsep`. With `@{}` at the sides I announce that I don't want the padding LaTeX usually adds at the sides of a tabular.

Comment: thanks egreg.
`\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}` seems to correct the vertical alignement of the second cell text, but it does not seem however to move up the graphic. Do you have any idea?